# MS Access VBA - system crashing during do until loop

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to calculate the number of days between two dates on a form, excluding weekends. However, the system keeps crashing every time it runs the do until loop. Can you spot where I might be going wrong within the code below?

Thanks for your help!

```
Private Sub total_text_Click()
Dim v_weekendcount As Integer
Dim v_date As Date
Dim dateone As Date
Dim datetwo As Date

v_date = Me.startdate_text.Value
v_weekendcount = 0

Do Until v_date = Me.enddate_text.Value
If Day(v_date) = vbSaturday Or Day(v_date) = vbSunday Then
v_weekendcount = v_weekendcount + 1
v_date = v_date + 1
End If
Loop

dateone = Me.startdate_text.Value
datetwo = Me.enddate_text.Value

Me.total_text.Value = DateDiff("d", dateone, datetwo) - v_weekendcount

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably had this in mind:

```
Do Until v_date = DateValue(Me.enddate_text.Value)
    If Weekday(v_date) = vbSaturday Or Weekday(v_date) = vbSunday Then
        v_weekendcount = v_weekendcount + 1
    End If
    v_date = v_date + 1
Loop
```

Comment: This is why nesting your `IF` statements, `Do` Statements and `For Each` statements is important. If the correct nesting had been done, this would have been much more visible as the mistake

Comment: Thank you, this stopped the system from crashing! However, it's not excluding weekends from the total_days calculation for some reason. Can you see what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just to exclude the possibility change the following line accordingly:

```
If (Day(v_date) = vbSaturday) Or (Day(v_date) = vbSunday) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the v_date = v_date + 1 call within the check for weekend. Doesn't this mean when it's not a weekend day it won't increment the date?